# Import Tally Data into Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to import data from Tally into a SQL Server Database.

I have searched in Internet also but not found any solution.

Can any one tell how we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look at Tally's [Data Migration Tools](http://www.tallysolutions.com/website/html/solutions/data-migrationtools.php)?

If you scroll a little down the page, there's a tool called "Tally.ERP 9 to SQL Databases". This sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: I have used this Software and I have also change the Connection String from MS Access to SQL Server but still the Data is not appearing in sql server. It is still showing in MS Access Database.